# Getting Id of a Textview in a fragment OnCreate() method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to get the Id of a text view in a fragment's `onCreate()` method. It returns `null` everytime.

I want to display my contacts in a fragment. For that at the end of `FetchContact()` method I assign the contact list to `TextView`.

Since my code is returning `null` when I find the `TextView` my application gives `NullPointerException`.
Anyone who could tell me how to get the `Id` of `TextView` of a `Fragment` in `onCreate()` method.

I tried making an object of activity class to get the `TextView`, still the code returned `null`. No luck.

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {

public TextView outputtext;
Context context;

class ActivityObj extends Activity{
    public TextView text;
    Context objContext;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textContact);
       objContext = getApplicationContext();
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActivityObj obj = new ActivityObj();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    outputtext =(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textContact);
 //  outputtext= obj.text;
    context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    //fetchContacts();

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Where is the text view? Belongs to fragment or activity layout? And why is activity class nested in Fragment? Fragment is hosted by a Activity. I suggest you read the fragment documentation first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this on onActivityCreated method

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        }
    }
```

Or use callbacks

Comment: Thank you too for accepting, cuz i've answered several times on StackOverflow but many rude people didn't accept my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> find the TextView my application gives NullPointerException.

Because in Fragment lifecycle `onCreate` method called before `onCreateView` method.

override `onViewCreated` which call after `onCreateView` method and use use first parameter of `onViewCreated` method for accessing views from Fragment layout:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView text =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textContact);
         /// your code here....
}
```

Comment: The onActivityCreated() method is also called after onCreateView() ,that worked for me. Thanks anyway!:)

Answer (score 2):

use

`rootView.findViewById(R.id....)` in your oncreateView there is where you should do the UI related work

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot initialize any view using **findViewById** before `onCreateView` method calls.

So you must have to wait for the `callback` to run. And there are two ways to get it. And it will work on `onActivityCreated` because it called after onCreateView

1. As described by **ρяσѕρєя K** using the `View param` came from onViewCreated.
2. You can call `getView()` in any callback(delegate) which call after
   onCreateView()

Like

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
```